# Prevent Xcode to rebuild project on any file changes

Tags: xcode, build, background, recompile

Xcode rebuilds my project and every subproject if any change was made in a dependent swift file.

It works ugly and is very annoying.
CPU is always busy, dialog window constantly appears and prevents to run a current project because this window doesn't work as expected, I always have to close it manually and build&run again and again.
Moreover Mac freezes when Xcode recompiles every project and waits for every key press for a few seconds.

How to disable this automatic background recompile?

I've disabled a "Show live issues" in General Settings, but it didn't help.

I have three plugins installed:

- SCXcodeMinimap
- Swift Refactorator
- XcodeColors

I've tryed to remove them, but it didn't help too.

Please, help me stop this ancestor of the Skynet!

P.S. Xcode Version 7.3.1 (7D1014)

Comment: Did you by any chance find a solution to the problem? I encounter the same problem in my project and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs when you use @IBDesignables in your interface builder. To stop xcode react every file changes:

- Open your storyboard
- Go to Editor
- Disable 'Automatically Refresh Views'

Original answer: [link](https://holko.pl/2017/11/15/rebuilding-ibdesignables/)